# I am the leader of the alphabet

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, language

A simple one-liner:

> I am the leader of the alphabet.

What am I?

Comment: Hello @Synchronous. This question appears to be open ended and could get many answers depending on the languages. Please consider that. rot13 (Nycunorg vf nyfb n Ovt Pbzcnal naq unf znal "Yrnqref" vapyhqvat sbhaqref naq pheerag PRB. Fb gung pbhyq or pbashfvat)

Comment: Thanks @DrD for the fair warning. I've added another tag which I think fits, but even without it I haven't been able to think of alternative answers. Your example wouldn't fit the `language` tag.

Comment: Their current leader has a non-english name which has a specific meaning in his country of origin language.

Comment: @DrD Alright, wordplay tag to the rescue then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The word alphabet begins with the word alpha. Alpha means the leader, or the main dominance in a group. Also, alpha is the first letter of the Greek alphabet and is transliterated to the letter a.
>
>  The answer is alpha.

Comment: Lucky you, you solved it right before they closed the question! The answer is your second guess. Nice going, remove your first guess and I'll give you a checkmark.